# R - min, max and mean of off-diagonal elements in a matrix

Tags: r, sum, mean

I have like a matrix in R and I want to get:

```
Max off - diagonal elements
Min off – diagonal elements
Mean off –diagonal elements
```

With diagonal I used max(diag(A)) , min(diag(A)) , mean(diag(A)) and worked just fine

But for off-diagonal I tried

```
dataD <- subset(A, V1!=V2)

Error in subset.matrix(A, V1 != V2) : object 'V1' not found
```

to use:

```
colMeans(dataD) # get the mean for columns
```

but I cannot get dataD b/c it says object 'V1' not found

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "off diagonal", do you mean all elements of the matrix **except** the diagonal or do you mean the row/col immediately above/below the diagonal?

Comment: Just loop through the elements in the matrix and ignore the diagonal elements. What's stopping you?

Comment: @JackManey looping when there is a vectorised solution is exceedingly inefficient in R.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here the `row()` and `col()` helper functions are useful. Using @James `A`, we can get the upper off-diagonal using this little trick:

```
> A[row(A) == (col(A) - 1)]
[1]  5 10 15
```

and the lower off diagonal via this:

```
> A[row(A) == (col(A) + 1)]
[1]  2  7 12
```

These can be generalised to give whatever diagonals you want:

```
> A[row(A) == (col(A) - 2)]
[1]  9 14
```

and don't require any subsetting.

Then it is a simple matter of calling whatever function you want on these values. E.g.:

```
> mean(A[row(A) == (col(A) - 1)])
[1] 10
```

If as per my comment you mean *everything but the diagonal*, then use

```
> diag(A) <- NA
> mean(A, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 8.5
> max(A, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 15
> # etc. using sum(A, na.rm = TRUE), min(A, na.rm = TRUE), etc..
```

So this doesn't get lost, Ben Bolker suggests (in the comments) that the above code block can be done more neatly using the `row()` and `col()` functions I mentioned above:

```
mean(A[row(A)!=col(A)])
min(A[row(A)!=col(A)])
max(A[row(A)!=col(A)])
sum(A[row(A)!=col(A)])
```

which is a nicer solution all round.

Comment: or `mean(A[row(A)!=col(A)])` etc.

Comment: +1 Ben - I saw you'd covered that option so didn't edit it into mine. That didn't even occur to me, even though I was using `row()` and `col()` to get the other bits. Total blank there.

Comment: I deleted mine since you'd covered most of it, with more explanation and examples.

Comment: I want to get the sum, min , max and mean for everything under and above diagonal i.e. in A sum everything above diagonal is 5 + 9 +10 +13 +14 + 15 = 66 , mean = 11 .....

Comment: The last code block shows how to get some of these. use `sum()`, and `min()` for the other two. Also see Ben Bolkers comment here which has a different approach.

Answer (score 7):

In one simple line of code:

For a matrix A if you wish to find the **Minimum**, 1st Quartile, Median, **Mean**, 3rd Quartile and **Maximum** of the upper **and** lower off diagonals:

`summary(c(A[upper.tri(A)],A[lower.tri(A)]))`.

Comment: `mean(A[lower.tri(A) | upper.tri(A)])` should be more efficient

Answer (score 4):

The `diag` of a suitably subsetted matrix will give you the off-diagonals. For example:

```
A <- matrix(1:16,4)
#upper off-diagonal
diag(A[-4,-1])
[1]  5 10 15
#lower off-diagonal
diag(A[-1,-4])
[1]  2  7 12
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a vector holding the max of the off-diagonal elements of *each col or row* of a matrix requires a few more steps. I was directed here when searching for help on that. Perhaps others will do the same, so I offer this solution, which I found using what I learned here.

The trick is to create a matrix of only the off-diagonal elements. Consider:

```
> A <- matrix(c(10,2,3, 4,10,6, 7,8,10), ncol=3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10    4    7
[2,]    2   10    8
[3,]    3    6   10
> apply(A, 2, max)
[1] 10 10 10
```

Subsetting using the suggested indexing, `A[row(A)!=col(A)]` produces a vector of off-diagonal elements, in column-order:

```
> v <- A[row(A)!=col(A)]
> v
[1] 2 3 4 6 7 8
```

Returning this to a matrix allows the use of `apply()` to  apply a function of choice to a margin of only off-diagonal elements. Using the `max` function as an example:

```
> A.off <- matrix(v, ncol=3)
> A.off
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    7
[2,]    3    6    8
> v <- apply(A.off, 2, max)
> v
[1] 3 6 8
```

The whole operation can be compactly—and rather cryptically—coded in one line:

```
> v <- apply(matrix(A[row(A)!=col(A)], ncol=ncol(A)), 2, max)
> v
[1] 3 6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply matrix A by 1-diag (nofelements)

for example if A is a 4x4 matrix, then

mean(A*(1-diag(4)) or A*(1-diag(nrow(A)))

This is faster when you need to run the same line of code multiple times

Answer (score -1):

In addition to James' answer, I want to add that you can use the diag function to directly exclude all diagonal elements of a matrix by use of `A[-diag(A)]`. For example, consider:
`summary(A[-diag(A)])`

Comment: I was very excited by the compactness of this answer, but I think it doesn't actually work in general. Compare  `m <- matrix(2:17,nrow=4); m[-diag(m)]; m[row(m)!=col(m)]`

Comment: Damn, you are right, my bad. For larger matrices, my idea would have to be used in the form of `A[-which(A %in% diag(A))]`, which is far less elegant than yours.

Comment: I don't think that works either ... `diag(A)` returns the *values* on the diagonal, so if there were entries that were repeated among the diagonal and off-diagonal elements, this would fail ...

Comment: Hm, unfortunately, you are correct. Complete failure from my side. 

A last try: `m[-seq(from=1,by=nrow(m)+1, length.out=nrow(m))]` 

That should work, although it is very inelegant.