# Zeroing some entries of matrix parallel to matrix diagonal in R

Tags: r, matrix

In R I would like to set to zero all entries of matrix a few entries above (and below) matrix diagonal. Example below for N x N matrix with N = 5 and we delete k=3 lines of entries parallel to matrix diagonal :

```
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 -->      a1  b1 00 00 00  
b2 a2 b2 c2 d2 -->      b2  a2 b2 00 00  
c3 b3 a3 b3 c3 -->      00  b3 a3 b3 00  
d4 c4 b4 a4 b4 -->      00  00 b4 a4 b4  
e5 d5 c5 b5 a5 -->      00  00 00 b5 a5  

(00 means the same as 0)
```

for k=2 we have

```
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 -->      a1 b1 c1 00 00  
b2 a2 b2 c2 d2 -->      b2 a2 b2 c2 00  
c3 b3 a3 b3 c3 -->      c3 b3 a3 b3 c3  
d4 c4 b4 a4 b4 -->      00 c4 b4 a4 b4  
e5 d5 c5 b5 a5 -->      00 00 c5 b5 a5
```

I've wrote simple function based on two consecutive for() loops, but this function is too slow if I deal with large number of small matrices, all matrices are N x N with N in range 400:450 and k is always in range of 350:370, all matrix entries are in range between -1 and 1 (I deal with correlation matrices), the amount of data is a few GB, so I need some vectorized version of function. Is it faster to set entries to zero or to copy choosen entries to new matrix ?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13049778/602276

Comment: possible duplicate of [R - min, max and mean of off-diagonal elements in a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049575/r-min-max-and-mean-of-off-diagonal-elements-in-a-matrix)

Comment: @Thomas It's not an exact duplicate, so I didn't flag it.  The answer is very helpful though, and I used it as the inspiration to post an answer to this question.

Comment: @Thomas I edited my question bu adding case where N=5 and k=3 pleasee look at role of parameter k and if you could please remove your vote for closing this question

Comment: @Andrie Yes, I thought maybe you weren't going to answer, when you did gave you a +1. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
d <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5)


zero.them<-function(x, n){
  x2<-x
  diag(x)<-0
  for(i in 1:n){
    diag(x[,(-1:-i)])<-0
    diag(x[(-1:-i),])<-0
    }
  x2[which(x==x2)] <- 0
  return(x2)
}

zero.them(d, 1) # for 1 above and below the diagonal

           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
[1,]  1.3709584 -0.10612452  0.0000000  0.000000 0.000000
[2,] -0.5646982  1.51152200  2.2866454  0.000000 0.000000
[3,]  0.0000000 -0.09465904 -1.3888607 -2.656455 0.000000
[4,]  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.2787888 -2.440467 1.214675
[5,]  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  1.320113 1.895193

zero.them(d, 2) # for 2 above and below the diagonal

           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  1.3709584 -0.10612452  1.3048697  0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] -0.5646982  1.51152200  2.2866454 -0.2842529  0.0000000
[3,]  0.3631284 -0.09465904 -1.3888607 -2.6564554 -0.1719174
[4,]  0.0000000  2.01842371 -0.2787888 -2.4404669  1.2146747
[5,]  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.1333213  1.3201133  1.8951935
```

Comment: behaviour of your function is correct, but is it possible to replace for() loop with some other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13049778/602276

Try this:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5)

offDiagonal <- function(x, offset=1, diagonal=TRUE){
  off <- (row(x) == (col(x) - offset) | row(x) == (col(x) + offset))  
  if(diagonal) diag(off) <- TRUE
  off
}


mat[!offDiagonal(mat)] <- 0
mat

          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -2.788105 -0.8399604  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
[2,]  1.194179 -0.6940815  0.3340976  0.0000000  0.00000000
[3,]  0.000000  0.2256085  0.8885540 -0.3661173  0.00000000
[4,]  0.000000  0.0000000 -1.8024987 -0.1903742 -0.65395419
[5,]  0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.4074090  0.08818081
```

Use the `offset` argument to specify a wider off-diagonal band:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5)
mat[!offDiagonal(mat, offset=2)] <- 0
mat

          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.4433126  0.0000000  1.0448629 0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000 -0.2439675  0.0000000 0.1703401  0.0000000
[3,] 0.2859253  0.0000000 -0.7731495 0.0000000 -0.1722833
[4,] 0.0000000  1.1120145  0.0000000 1.0412452  0.0000000
[5,] 0.0000000  0.0000000  1.0860853 0.0000000 -0.3957575
```

Comment: but what about parameter k from my question, for your implemenation k is always N-2

Comment: I used the argument `offset` to do this. Try setting `offset=2`, `offset=3`, etc.

Comment: I've edited my question by adding case with N=5 and k=2

Comment: @Qbik As I said, use the `offset` argument.  I added another example, but the function remains the same.

Comment: @Andrie please look on Frank solution, output is correct, but still contain for() loop

Comment: @Qbik Please describe what you perceive to be incorrect about my solution.  To me, it looks the same, so please tell me what you need extra, or what I'm missing.

Comment: line : mat[!offDiagonal(mat, offset=2)] <- 0
 gives incorrect solution

Comment: If you tell me what is wrong with the solution, I can try and fix it.  Right now, I don't understand what you want me to fix.

Comment: @Andrie In your second example there are two diagonal "lines" of 0s that immediately flank the diagonal.  One of those "lines" is made of these points: `mat[2,1]`, `mat[3,2]`, `mat[4,3]` and `mat[5,4]` which are all 0, but should not be.

Comment: Perhaps, "off" needs to be `Reduce("|", lapply(seq_len(offset), function(n) (row(x) == (col(x) - n) | row(x) == (col(x) + n))))` or a similar approach?