# Get all diagonal vectors from matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to figure out how to get all the diagonals of a matrix.
For example, say I have the following matrix:
A <- matrix(1:16,4)

using the `diag(A)` function will return

```
[1]  1  6 11 16
```

In addition to the primary diagonal, I would like a list of all the diagonals above and below it.

```
5 10 15
2  7 12
9 14
3  8
4
13
```

I found the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13049722 which gives me the diagonals directly above and below the primary one, however I cannot seem to figure out how to extend the code to get the rest of them for any size matrix.  I tried two nested for loops since it appears that some kind of incrementing of the matrix subscripts would produce the result I am looking for.  I tried using ncol(A), nrow(A) in the for loops, but couldn't seem to figure out the right combination.  Plus I am aware that for loops are generally frowned upon in R.

The code given was:

```
diag(A[-4,-1])
diag(A[-1,-4])
```

which returned the two diagonals, both upper and lower

Of course this is a square matrix and not all of the matrices I want to perform this on will be square.  Filling in the non-square area with NAs would be acceptable if necessary.  The answer I need may be in one of the other answers on the page, but the original question involved means, sums, etc. which added a layer of complexity beyond what I am trying to do.  I have a feeling the solution to this will be ridiculously simple, but it just isn't occurring to me.  I'm also surprised I was not able to find this question anywhere on SO, it would seem to be a common enough question.  Maybe I don't know the proper terminology for this problem.

Comment: Why aren't you looking at @GavinSimpson's answer there?

Comment: I did read that answer as well which is why I understand the solution involves incrementing based on the number of rows and columns, however how to package this up as a function that returns all the diagonals in one matrix is what is evading me here.  I read all the answers repeatedly.

Comment: Side note:  `for` loops are not frowned upon. That's a myth (IMO).  They're all over the source code.  They just need to be used appropriately, like any other function. :-)

Comment: @RichardScriven - it's not a myth that `for` loops are frowned upon. It is however a myth that all that frowning necessarily has any impact on the speed of the code.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
A <- matrix(1:16, 4)

# create an indicator for all diagonals in the matrix
d <- row(A) - col(A)

# use split to group on these values
split(A, d)

# 
# $`-3`
# [1] 13
# 
# $`-2`
# [1]  9 14
# 
# $`-1`
# [1]  5 10 15
# 
# $`0`
# [1]  1  6 11 16
# 
# $`1`
# [1]  2  7 12
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 3 8
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 4
```

Comment: and can be changed for reverse diagonals `row(A) + col(A)`

Answer (score 6):

Since you're dealing with square matrices, it should be really easy to convert Gavin's answer into a small function that first calculates the range that should be used as the offset values. Here's such a function:

```
AllDiags <- function(inmat, sorted = TRUE) {
  Range <- ncol(inmat) - 1
  Range <- -Range:Range
  if (isTRUE(sorted)) Range <- Range[order(abs(Range))]
  lapply(Range, function(x) {
    inmat[row(inmat) == (col(inmat) - x)]
  })
}
```

Here's the output on your sample matrix "A".

```
AllDiags(A)
# [[1]]
# [1]  1  6 11 16
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  2  7 12
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  5 10 15
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 3 8
# 
# [[5]]
# [1]  9 14
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 13
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution based on an observation that you can get all the diagonals by shrinking and expanding the matrix. That is first consider row N col 1 (get diag of that) then rows (N-1): and cols (1:2). Get diagonal of that. etc..

```
N <- ncol(A)
rows <- cbind(c(N:1, rep(1,N-1)), c(rep(N,N), (N-1):1)) # row indeces
cols <- apply(rows, 2, rev)                             # col indeces

diagMatSubset <- function(mat, i1, i2, j1, j2) diag(mat[i1:i2, j1:j2, drop=FALSE])

Map(diagMatSubset, list(A), rows[,1], rows[,2], cols[,1], cols[,2])

[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 3 8

[[3]]
[1]  2  7 12

[[4]]
[1]  1  6 11 16

[[5]]
[1]  5 10 15

[[6]]
[1]  9 14

[[7]]
[1] 13
```