# How to sum over diagonals of data frame

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, diagonal

Say that I have this data frame:

```
     1   2   3   4      
100  8   12  5   14 
99   1   6   4   3   
98   2   5   4   11  
97   5   3   7   2
```

In this above data frame, the values indicate counts of how many observations take on `(100, 1), (99, 1)`, etc.

In my context, the diagonals have the same meanings:

```
     1   2   3   4
100  A   B   C   D 
99   B   C   D   E  
98   C   D   E   F 
97   D   E   F   G
```

How would I sum across the diagonals (i.e., sum the counts of the like letters) in the first data frame?

This would produce:

```
group  sum
A      8
B      13
C      13
D      28
E      10
F      18
G      2
```

For example, `D` is `5+5+4+14`

Comment: Is this a matrix or a data.frame? (A matrix is easier to perform this on)

Comment: data.frame, but converting it to a matrix and back to a data.frame as in @Ben Bolker's answer does the trick.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27935555/1191259

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `row()` and `col()` to identify row/column relationships.

```
m <- read.table(text="
    1   2   3   4      
100  8   12  5   14 
99   1   6   4   3   
98   2   5   4   11  
97   5   3   7   2")

vals <- sapply(2:8,
       function(j) sum(m[row(m)+col(m)==j]))
```

or (as suggested in comments by ?@thelatemail)

```
vals <- sapply(split(as.matrix(m), row(m) + col(m)), sum)
data.frame(group=LETTERS[seq_along(vals)],sum=vals)
```

or (@Frank)

```
data.frame(vals = tapply(as.matrix(m), 
       (LETTERS[row(m) + col(m)-1]), sum))
```

`as.matrix()` is required to make `split()` work correctly ...

Comment: What is the logic for why one needs to convert it to a matrix (instead of leaving it in data.frame) in order to do this?

Comment: @BenBolker - row and col work on all "matrix-like" objects with 2 dimensions incl. matrices, data.frames, tables etc.

Comment: Another very similar one:  `data.frame(vals = tapply(as.matrix(m), (LETTERS[row(m) + col(m)-1]), sum))
`

Answer (score 7):

Another `aggregate` variation, avoiding the formula interface, which actually complicates matters in this instance:

```
aggregate(list(Sum=unlist(dat)), list(Group=LETTERS[c(row(dat) + col(dat))-1]), FUN=sum)

#  Group Sum
#1     A   8
#2     B  13
#3     C  13
#4     D  28
#5     E  10
#6     F  18
#7     G   2
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution using bgoldst's definition of `df1` and `df2`

```
sapply(unique(c(as.matrix(df2))),
       function(x) sum(df1[df2 == x]))
```

Gives

```
#A  B  C  D  E  F  G 
#8 13 13 28 10 18  2
```

(Not quite the format that you wanted, but maybe it's ok...)

Comment: Forgot to mention that my solution assumes that you have set `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using `stack()`, and `aggregate()`, although it requires the second data.frame contain character vectors, as opposed to factors (could be forced with `lapply(df2,as.character)`):

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(8,1,2,5), b=c(12,6,5,3), c=c(5,4,4,7), d=c(14,3,11,2) );
df2 <- data.frame(a=c('A','B','C','D'), b=c('B','C','D','E'), c=c('C','D','E','F'), d=c('D','E','F','G'), stringsAsFactors=F );
aggregate(sum~group,data.frame(sum=stack(df1)[,1],group=stack(df2)[,1]),sum);
##   group sum
## 1     A   8
## 2     B  13
## 3     C  13
## 4     D  28
## 5     E  10
## 6     F  18
## 7     G   2
```