# faster alternative to compute colCumsums of a band matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R and stats.In the domain I am currently working in, I am required to compute the cumulative column sums in a unique manner.

Initially a square band matrix of width b and number of rows n is provided.For example for n = 8 and b = 3

```
0 1 2 7 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 6 7 0 0 0
0 0 0 3 1 7 0 0
0 0 0 0 4 4 7 0
0 0 0 0 0 5 8 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then the matrix is to be transformed in such a way that a n x b matrix with diagonals as columns are obtained.Like for the given example,

```
1 2 7  
3 6 7 
3 1 7 
4 4 7 
5 8 7 
1 8 0
4 0 0
0 0 0
```

I am currently using the following function to perform this operation.

```
     packedband <- function(x, n, b) {
      mat <- sapply(0:(b-1), function(i)
         diag(x[-(n:(n-i)), -(1:(1+i))])[1:n] )
      mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
      return(mat)
      }
```

And then apply the colCumsums function from matrixStats packageto obtain the desired output matrix.For the given example,

```
1    2     7
4    8    14
7    9    21
11   13   28
16   21   35
17   29   35
21   29   35
21   29   35
```

What I am looking for is a faster computation of these operations since in the given domain,the number of columns(or rows) can be > 10^5.Probably the step of calculating packedband function can be removed since the end goal is to obtain cumulative column sum.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what should be the output. If you just want col sums use function `colSums()`? Also there is function `abandSparse(n, m = n, k, diagonals, symmetric = FALSE, giveCsparse = TRUE)`.

Comment: @mkty `colCumsums` is not a base R function. Please mention the name of the package in which the function resides. @Mislav same for `abandSparse`.

Comment: @lmo I have modified the question.Please have a look.

Comment: Here is one way to organize your matrix for `colCumsums`. `library(Matrix); m = as(d, "TsparseMatrix") ; m = sparseMatrix(i = m@i+1,  j = m@j - m@i,  x = m@x, dims = c(nrow(d),3))` (where 3 is hardcoded for the bandwidth )

Comment: or without using sparseMatrix: `m = as(d, "TsparseMatrix") ; m2 = matrix(0, nrow(d), 3) ; m2[cbind(m@i+1, m@j - m@i)] <- m@x` , In fact without MAtrix at all: `nz = which(d != 0, arr.ind=TRUE) ; 
nz = cbind(nz, d  = nz[,"col"] - nz[,"row"]) ; 
mn = matrix(0, nrow(d), 3) ; mn[cbind(nz[,"row"], nz[,"d"])] <- d[d!=0]`

Comment: In fact this might be quicker `dd = cbind(d, matrix(0, nrow=nrow(d), ncol=3)) ; ro = seq_len(nrow(d)) ; matrix(dd[cbind(ro, ro + rep(1:3, each=nrow(dd)))], ncol=3)`

Comment: @user20650 Thank you for your beautiful answer.It does perform faster.Also, can we obtain the desired output (colcumsums matrix) without computing the 2nd matrix(in which diagonals are obtained as columns)? Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: Yes, but I think you would have to loop through the columns, and apply colsums to each diagonal one at a time. I would think it would be faste rto apply colcumsums once, s you already do. There may be a linear algebra way but I dont see it.

Comment: @user20650 Thanks for your response.Can we make use of the vector form of sparse matrix, i.e  (1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 3, 7, 1, 4 and so on)

Comment: Yes,  but i cant see how to do it without a loop / using a grouping variable. There is also the slight complication of uneven numbers in each diagonal, so you have to pad with extra zeros, hence the use of the intermediate matrix. There is probably a fast solution using a for loop. . btw, although the first sparse matrix solutions is slower, the time is taken coercing it the matrix to sparse. If you had initially stored the band matrix as sparse, creating the intermediate matrix is *much* faster.

Answer (score 0):

After messing about with sparse matrices, I think a `for` loop may work well here.

Try on original data

```
d = as.matrix(read.table(text="0 1 2 7 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 6 7 0 0 0
0 0 0 3 1 7 0 0
0 0 0 0 4 4 7 0
0 0 0 0 0 5 8 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "))

colnames(d) <- NULL
```

Functions

```
packedband <- function(x, b=3) {
      n = nrow(d)
      mat <- sapply(0:(b-1), function(i)
                  diag(x[-(n:(n-i)), -(1:(1+i))])[1:n] )
      mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
      matrixStats::colCumsums(mat)
   }

forloop <- function(d, b=3){
     n = nrow(d)
     m = matrix(0, n, b)
      for(i in 1:b) {
        ro = 1:(n-i)
        co = (1+i):n
        vec = `length<-`(d[cbind(ro, co)], n)
        vec[is.na(vec)] <- 0
        m[ , i] = cumsum(vec)
      }
     m
   }

# create initial sparse matrix just to omit time to convert
# as if its faster it may be worth storing your band matrices in sparse format
library(Matrix)
m <- as(d, "TsparseMatrix") 

spm <- function(m, b=3){
x = sparseMatrix(i = m@i+1,
                 j = m@j - m@i,
                 x = m@x,
                 dims = c(nrow(m),b))
matrixStats::colCumsums(as.matrix(x))
}

all.equal(forloop(d), packedband(d))
all.equal(spm(m), packedband(d))
```

Try with bigger data

```
d = matrix(0, 5e3, 5e3)
d[(col(d) - row(d)) == 1] <- 1
d[(col(d) - row(d)) == 2] <- 1
d[ (col(d) - row(d)) == 3] <- 1

m <- as(d, "TsparseMatrix") 

all.equal(forloop(d), packedband(d))
all.equal(spm(m), packedband(d))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(packedband(d), forloop(d), spm(m), times=50)
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
#  packedband(d) 1348240.520 1724714.293 1740634.707 1733305.192 1763377.869 1960353.263    50   b
#     forloop(d)     720.344     973.658    1054.461    1026.807    1174.731    1565.912    50  a 
#         spm(m)    2145.875    2437.321    2586.503    2480.133    2749.019    3766.051    50  a
```

Comment: This is one gem of an answer.Thanks a lot for this solution!