# How can I save a specific element from a list?

Tags: r, list, split, save, element

Following this Stackoverflow question about how to get the diagonal vectors from a matrix ([Get all diagonal vectors from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935555/get-all-diagonal-vectors-from-matrix)) I was stuck when trying to save one of the elements.

```
A <- matrix(1:16, 4)
d <- row(A) - col(A)
d.chem <- split(A, d)
d.chem 
# $`-3`
# [1] 13
# 
# $`-2`
# [1]  9 14
# 
# $`-1`
# [1]  5 10 15
# 
# $`0`
# [1]  1  6 11 16
# 
# $`1`
# [1]  2  7 12
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 3 8
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 4
```

I would like to save just this element: $`-1`. How can I do it?
I tried the following but I got an error message:

```
    lapply(d.chem, '[[', 3)
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
    unlist(lapply(d.chem, '[[', 3))
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
d.chem$`-1`
```

Consider using `` signs to access "-1" named member of list.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy!!! I was trying that also but with different symbols. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the element via the index `d.chem[3]` as well