# Extracting off-diagonal elements of a matrix in R

Tags: r, function, matrix

The off-diagonal elements of the `mat_rix` below are all `0`s.

To extract the off-diagonal elements, I use a solution that I found on SO: `odiag <- function(x) x[(n <- nrow(x))^2-(1:n)*(n-1)]`

But when I use `odiag(mat_rix)`, the output contains `non-0` elements. I wonder what's the problem and how to fix it?

```
x="
 0.4850377 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.510766 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.05767389 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.07539841 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.3134951 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.679101 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.5067036 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.1829717 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3722585 0.0000000 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3907239 0.0000000
 0.0000000 0.000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0287955"

mat_rix <- as.matrix(read.table(text=x))

odiag(mat_rix)

[1] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.679101 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: It may be more informative to use an example of, for example, `matrix(1:16, 4, 4)` and then declare which values you would like extracted. It a bit hard to see if the correct values, or the order in which they are extracted is correct if they are all zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need the off-diagonal, create a function where the `row` index is not equal to `col`umn index

```
odiag <- function(x) x[col(x) != row(x)]
odiag(mat_rix)
```

If we need the values that are one up/one down from the diagonal

```
odiag2 <- function(x, offdiag = "up") {
    ind <- if(offdiag == "up") -1 else 1
    x[row(x) - col(x) == ind]
}
odiag2(mat_rix, "up")
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thinking you and OP `might` have different 'off diagonal' expectations as your off is all off, agnostic as to upper or lower off, hence length 110, in this case, where it appears OP is looking for 'one' off, again agnostic to upper lower, but length 10.

Comment: @Chris I posted this as comment and the OP told me to post as a solution.  So, I would assume that this is what OP meant

Comment: I was looking at the length of his prior output, which wasn't complained of, except the indexing that brought in the non-zero, But his check will clarify.

Comment: @Chris I noticed that too.  That is the reason I commented and then he replied.  I would have kept my comments below his post

Comment: And choosing one's diagonal from those available [extracting off diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935555/get-all-diagonal-vectors-from-matrix) using `split`.

Comment: A question of interest [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70490158/16762740).

Comment: @SimonHarmel it seems to be deleted though